# Make: start process that if being killed, does not kill make

Tags: make, ram

I use `GNU make` to start benchmarks of different write/read calls in R. In some cases this will result in my RAM being fully used and the process being killed (which is fine, since I want to see the limits).

The issue however is, that the whole make process is killed and not only the specific script-call.

For example, say I have the following `Makefile`, the target `small.csv` works fine, `large.csv` crashes (kinda expected), but now the other `...` targets are not build.

The question is, how can I start the process (`Rscript tester --size large`) in a way, that `make` can continue the other (`...`) benchmarks after one process has been killed?

```
# Makefile

.PHONY: all

all: small.csv large.csv ...

small.csv: tester.R
    Rscript tester.R --size small

large.csv: tester.R
    Rscript tester.R --size large

...
```

Note that the script touches the target in the first lines, so the target is always created, regardless of whether the run was killed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because Make stops execution by default if any command indicates that it failed.

You can disable this by [prefixing commands with `-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors):

```
small.csv: tester.R
        -Rscript tester.R --size small

large.csv: tester.R
        -Rscript tester.R --size large
```

Alternatively, you can run `make` with the `-k` option to tell it to keep going as far as possible after errors occur.